# How to get private key in cpp-ethereum?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, private-key

I can only find instructions for `geth`, but cannot find anything about doing it using `eth` which is part of `cpp-ethereum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question. In short, the answer is `ethkey` tool that comes with `cpp-ethereum`.

As a demonstration, I will create some eth wallet on www.myetherwallet.com, import it into cpp-ethereum, and then display its private key.

### 1. Create some dummy eth wallet on www.myetherwallet.com

I created eth address `0x698042d6233042632711C86452A53a8E9637F585` with private key: `a2fc86c38a1a7fb6c0eaea9696d6434cd977dbef46fba3183ac99ad42d2f62ef`.

https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info

[image]

### 2. Import it into `cpp-ethereum`

```
./ethkey importbare a2fc86c38a1a7fb6c0eaea9696d6434cd977dbef46fba3183ac99ad42d2f62ef
```

You will be asked for password. Give some.

```
Enter a passphrase with which to secure account 698042d6…: 
Please confirm the passphrase by entering it again: 
Successfully imported a2fc86c38a1a7fb6c0eaea9696d6434cd977dbef46fba3183ac99ad42d2f62ef as 1c15859c-c3eb-0328-36bc-1ac17792d986
```

Not that the private key was imported as `1c15859c-c3eb-0328-36bc-1ac17792d986`. This means that file `~/.web3/keys/1c15859c-c3eb-0328-36bc-1ac17792d986.json` was created.

### 3. Display private key

Using the `ethkey`, show the private key:

```
./ethkey --show-me-the-secret  inspectbare 1c15859c-c3eb-0328-36bc-1ac17792d986
```

The result is:

```
Enter passphrase for key 1c15859c-c3eb-0328-36bc-1ac17792d986: 
Key 1c15859c-c3eb-0328-36bc-1ac17792d986:
  ICAP: XE17CBNICXRZJEY6DAJHNL1J8VTUM39OL1H
  Raw hex: 698042d6233042632711c86452a53a8e9637f585
  Secret: a2fc86c38a1a7fb6c0eaea9696d6434cd977dbef46fba3183ac99ad42d2f62ef
```

where `Secret` is our private key, while `Raw hex` is our `address`.

Comment: Why do you use myetherwallet? The private key is just a random number, which you can get through much more secure means... For example, `openssl rand -hex 32` if you have openssl, or you can use `/dev/urandom` on unix systems

Comment: @TjadenHess No particular reason as only to show this example and that the the private key from myetherewallet agrees with `ethkey`  results.